# ¿En cuál dialecto español se pronuncia "Y" como [j]?

Tags: pronunciación, dialectos, estados-unidos

Yo estuve en una tienda hace tiempo, y vi una familia hablando en español sobre las cosas que iban a comprar. El padre dijo la palabra "mayonesa," y un niño hizo una mueca.

Lo que me llamó la atención es que cuando él dijo "mayonesa," él lo dijo como se deletree "mai-onesa," y no con el sonido normal de la letra "y" (es decir, [majo'nesa] en lugar de [maʝo'nesa]). Yo nunca habia escuchado esto antes, y me pregunto si es un dialecto nativo, o un efecto de hablar inglés (vivo en EEUU) y español todos los días.

Mi ciudad tiene una comunidad de inmigrantes guatemaltecos, ¿podría ser la pronunciación guatemalteca?

Comment: Para ti, que es `el sonido normal de la letra "y."`?

Comment: Para mí, creo que es [ʝ], según estas páginas:
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonolog%C3%ADa_del_espa%C3%B1ol
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fricativa_palatal_sonora

Answer (score 4, accepted):

J.G. Moreno (1994) y J. Matluck (2003) argumentan que en algunas regiones de México, `ll` e `y` se convierten en **prepalatales fricativas sonoras** cuando están entre dos vocales, excepto cuando están antes de `i` (no es lo mismo que [ʝ], una palatal fricativa sonora que corresponde a la pronunciación "estandar" de las grafías `ll` e `y`). Ambos autores representan ese sonido de la siguiente manera:

[image: i]

En palabras de Matluck, la pronunciación "se acerca más al tipo redondeado [j] que a la [ʝ] consonántica".

Por eso, en algunas partes de México, cuando la gente dice leyes, pollo, arroyo, o mayo, parece que dice "lei'es", "poi'o", "arroi'o", o "mai'o".

No sé si sea un fenómeno que también se generalizó en Centroamérica, pero al menos en México pasa :)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Véase José G. Moreno de Alba, *La pronuncación del español de México*, el Colegio de México, México, 1994;</sup>
<sup>J. Matluck, *La pronunciación del español en el valle de México*, en A. Rivas y Y. Rodrígues (eds.), Antología Conmemorativa: Nueva revista de filología hispánica,  el Colegio de México, México, 2003.</sup>